# How to configure where OpenVPN server reads client certs?

Tags: openvpn

We run OpenVPN servers on several autoscaled instances (for redundancy and self-healing) so it's provisioned in a scripted manner.  Our approach for managing client certificates across these ephemeral instances is pretty clumsy, and currently involves extracting a tarball into the `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki` directory.

I'd like to move only the client certs to a shared network directory, but I haven't been able to figure out what config settings inform openvpn about these pki subdirectories.  (The `ca/cert/key/dh` settings all point deep into the hierarchy, i.e. `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/server.crt`, which implies to me there wouldn't be any built-in assumptions about the easy-rsa directory structure.)

How does openvpn find these files?

Comment: hows about tp use an nfs share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and thank you for the question...

It is a little bit easier that you think ;-). You don't need all client certificates. Client certificates are needed for the client...

Next to the configuration file there are 3-4 generated and "linked" files which could be embeded as section in the config file directly (these are all you need to have on the server / client ).

- TLS key (optional but not bad to use ;-) )

This is shared key to secure the communication even before start client specific traffic - without knowing this key the server simply ignore your communication. This file is the same on the server and the client

- CA
  Certification authority what is the certificate which is used to confirm trust of remote side.

  - **server**: Certificate of the authority which is issuing client cert. THIS is what you are looking for - as this file can be used to check ALL issued client certs during the connection. This single file can be used to check current and also future certificates issued the by the same CA (that is what is covered by easy-rsa)
  - **client**: this file is used to check server cert that it is trusted. It can be the same like on server side but technically server cert could be issued by different CA than clients' certs.
- key

private key used for securing communication. This file should be kept secured as it is the file which confirming your identity.

- cert

certificate (public key "wrapped" with additional information related to Certification Authority in X.509 structure). This file can be even publicly available as it is used only for checking the communication for the validity (that the used key for the signature is really "that" trusted one).

---

As you have mentioned easy-rsa the CA is the most probably the same for client and server side. Once you have common TLS key, common CA file and own key with corresponding cert you have all you need to have it working.

Once you generate key and cert for the user and deliver it to the user (or at least send it out) you don't need it any more and this user key+cert could be even deleted from the server...

In the "big" Certification Authority the user key is not even known to the issuing server as the certification request contain public key (derived information from the private key) which is all needed to create signed certificate - the key is generated on the client side and never leave it by the process...